# How to add a vanillaJS npm script to a Nuxt plugin?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

I have an issue getting [AWS S3](https://github.com/Fausto95/aws-s3) to save images straight to AWS S3.

I tried to import the AWS package as a plugin but it doesn't work.

I do have the following in my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [
  ...
  '~plugins/S3.js'
],
```

in my `plugins/s3.js`

```js
import vue from "vue"
import S3 from "aws-s3";
vue.use(S3)
```

and I try to use it in my file

```js
const S3Client = new S3(config)
S3Client
.uploadFile(file, this.getRandomName(10))
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

I get the error

> multiplephotoupload.vue?7624:110 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: S3 is not defined

If I write it directly into my component, this is defined and working

```js
import S3 from "aws-s3";
```

Comment: yes, I said it only works if I import it that way, and it defeats the purpose of using it as a plugin.

Comment: Do you need to use it globally on several places?

Comment: Just in three components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use it as a Nuxt plugin (this will be available globally but will also increase the total bundle size and loading time of your app even in places you're not using it), you can do this in your `s3.js` plugin

```js
import S3 from 'aws-s3'

export default ({ _ }, inject) => {
  const config = {
    bucketName: 'myBucket',
    dirName: 'photos' /* optional */,
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    accessKeyId: 'ANEIFNENI4324N2NIEXAMPLE',
    secretAccessKey: 'cms21uMxçduyUxYjeg20+DEkgDxe6veFosBT7eUgEXAMPLE',
    s3Url: 'https://my-s3-url.com/' /* optional */,
  }
  inject('s3', new S3(config))
}
```

And you'll be able to access the instance with `this.$s3` in your Vue components!

This needs to be done with packages that are not exposing the Vue approach. More info in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context

---

Josh Deltener has a [great article](https://deltener.com/blog/nuxt-third-party-code-is-poison/) on this one with various approaches.

---

If you want to have dynamic options, you also can pass params to your injected value, as shown in the linked docs.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, how would you use AWS S3 in your Nuxt app

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi my backend team provided me a GraphQL query that gives me an upload URL.It expires pretty quickly and can be used only once, I use [nuxt-dropzone](https://github.com/Etheryte/nuxt-dropzone) to send the files there. Pretty flexible and does the job fine. But you can do it in a lot of ways IMO.