# Add sweet alert 2 to nuxt3 project

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, sweetalert2, nuxtjs3

I'm struggling to integrate sweet alert 2 as a plugin into a nuxt3 app. I'm trying to use [vue-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) but I at some point it define global variables.

```js
// Inside the install function
vue.prototype.$swal = swalFunction;
vue['swal'] = swalFunction;
```

Could you please help me, how to access these global variable? The documentation do not show that.

I guess the goal would be to have inside my plugin something like:

```js
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueSweetalert2)

  return {
    provide: {
      swal: swalFunction // <- how to access this ?
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I guess you've already read [this one](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins)? Did you checked [this one](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2)? Also, it's probably better to just locally import it, rather than globally (performance-wise). Or do you have a HEAVY usage of modals everywhere on your website? Otherwise, you could probably pass the `VueSweetalert2` import to `swal` and call it with `this.$swal.yourMethod` in your project. Somehow as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485267/8816585).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already read the documentation. However, I think this issue is specific to nuxt 3 because I can't access $swal in my components. I'm not using `this`. The nuxt3 guide do not indicate how to access global registered variable in the vue 3 (like `this.$swal`), nuxtApp.vueApp.swal is undefined) as it is encapsulated, this is why I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm learning nuxt3 too.Here is how I use sweet alert 2 in my app of nuxt3.

plugins/swal.js

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "@sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4";
const $swal = {
    install: (Vue, options) => {
        Vue.config.globalProperties.$swal = Swal.mixin(options);
    },
}
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use($swal, {
        reverseButtons: true,
        confirmButtonText: "confirmText",
        cancelButtonText: "cancelText",
        confirmButtonColor: "#84bd00",
    });
});
```

Usage in components

```
<script>
    export default {
      const fn = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties;
      fn.$swal.fire({
          title: "hello",
          timer: 2000,
      });
    }
</script>
```

Or use by provide and inject, My `plugins/swal.js` will be like this.

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "@sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4";
const options = {
    reverseButtons: true,
    confirmButtonText: "confirmText",
    cancelButtonText: "cancelText",
    confirmButtonColor: "#84bd00",
}
const $swal = {
    install: (Vue, options) => {
        Vue.provide("$swal", Swal.mixin(options));
    },
}
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use($swal, options);
});
```

Usage in components

```
<script>
    export default {
      const swal = inject("$swal");
      swal.fire({
          title: "hello",
          timer: 2000,
      });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I do not recommend the usage of mixins or a global instance (if not 100% needed).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up doing your second solution which works perfectly @Josh.H.


Waiting for the correct integration of sweet alert 2 :)

Answer (score 10):

**You can make it easier:**

plugins/sweetalert2.ts

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.provide('swal', Swal)
})
```

usage in `<script setup>`

```
const { $swal } = useNuxtApp()

$swal.fire({
  title: 'Error!',
  text: 'Do you want to continue',
  icon: 'error',
  confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading from `Nuxt2` to `Nuxt3` I've noticed the version `10.x.x` stopped working on `Nuxt3` (missing styles). After updating to the newest (`11.x.x`) it's working again and no changes in the code are needed.

My setup:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "sweetalert2": "^11.7.32",
  ...
}
```

**component.vue**

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
...
Swal.fire(
  'Awesome!',
  "We've received your mail, will get back to you A.S.A.P.",
  'success',
)
```

and no `Vue`-specific dependency is needed, such as `vue-sweetalert2`.

Comment: I can confirm this method worked

Answer (score 0):

This is how i made it work in nuxt 3.5

1. `npm i sweetalert2`
2. Add in plugins folder new file `sweetaler2.client.ts`

```js
import Swal, { SweetAlertOptions } from 'sweetalert2'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css'

// Default options
const options: SweetAlertOptions = {}

const $swal = {
    install: (Vue: any, options: SweetAlertOptions) => {
        Vue.provide('$swal', Swal.mixin(options))
    }
}
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use($swal, options)
})
```

3. Add a type safe composable `useSwal`

```js
import * as SweetAlert2 from 'sweetalert2'

export default function () {
    const useSwal = () => {
        return inject('$swal') as typeof SweetAlert2.default
    }
    return useSwal()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I finally found with Nuxt 3.5+ is to just create a composable.  Nuxt will automatically pull in types when added in a composable:

```js
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export function useSwal() {
  // update default options
  const Alert = Swal.mixin({
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    reverseButtons: true,
  });

  return {
    Alert,
  };
}
```

Then in my component setup:

```js
async function deleteValue(key: KeyValRef, val: string) {
  if (!key || !val) return;
  const { Alert } = useSwal();
  Alert.fire({
    title: "Delete Value?",
    text: `Are you sure you wish to remove ${val} from ${key}? This cannot be undone.`,
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, DELETE",
    cancelButtonText: "No",
  }).then(async (result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      await deleteValueFromKey(key, val);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file like useSwal.ts and add to auto imports:

```
import type { SweetAlertOptions } from 'sweetalert2';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js';
import 'swal-custom.scss';

const useSwal = () => {
    const swal = (options: SweetAlertOptions) => Swal.fire(options);
    swal.DismissReason = Swal.DismissReason;
    swal.close = Swal.close;
    return swal;
};

export default useSwal;
```

You can use custom scss in custom-swal.scss:

```
@import 'sweetalert2/src/variables';

// BOX MODEL
$swal2-width: 328px;
$swal2-padding: 16px;
$swal2-border-radius: 14px;
$swal2-box-shadow: 0 0 15px
    rgba(
        $color: black,
        $alpha: 0.15,
    );

// TYPOGRAPHY
$swal2-font-size: 14px;

...

@import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2';
```