# Agora sdk plugin not recognized in Nuxt 2

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm trying to setup Agora for live streaming in my nuxtjs app. But it gives an error saying plugin not recognized in the console and I can't seem to get past this issue. Did anyone encounter similar issues? My nuxt version is `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"` and agora `"agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "^4.13.0"`. The error I'm encountering now is: [image: plugin is undefined error]

I've imported the plugin in agora.js file in my plugins folder.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { AgoraRTC } from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng';

Vue.use(AgoraRTC);
```

And the nuxt config.

```
{
  src: "~/plugins/agora.js",
  ssr: false,
  mode: 'client'
}
```

###### EDIT:

If I update the agora.js file with this code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import AgoraRTC from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng';

Vue.use(AgoraRTC);
```

I get the error:  `ReferenceError: AgoraRTC is not defined`.
Am I missing something? Also it would be a great help if anyone could give reference to a demo build with nuxt.

Comment: The package you're importing is specific to Angular (`ng` at the end) of I'm not mistaken. Look for a regular JS or a Vue specific one IMO. Also, `ssr: false` is deprecated. You can keep only the `mode` here.

Comment: I don't think it is specific to Angular. And I did try removing the ssr part, renaming agora.js to agora.client.js. Yet no improvement.

Comment: There is no documentation on that package haha. Try another one IMO.

Comment: As the title of the question suggests, I'm using an SDK of agora. There are documentations of the SDK. So I guess the package doesn't need one separately.

Comment: Do you have a link for that one?

Comment: Here's the [link to Agora documentatiuon](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/product_live?platform=Web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding no solution to this, I contacted the support team of Agora. They had been a great help!

The problem was with `Vue.use(AgoraRTC)`. For some reason this wasn't working. So I had to inject it in the app.

First I replaced these sections form `plugins/agora.js` file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import AgoraRTC from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng';

Vue.use(AgoraRTC);
```

and `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
{
  src: "~/plugins/agora.js",
  ssr: false,
  mode: 'client'
}
```

With this:

```
import AgoraRTC from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng"

export default ({app}, inject) => {
    inject("AgoraRTC", AgoraRTC)
}
```

and:

```
{
  src: "~/plugins/agora.js",
  mode: 'client'
}
```

Finally the `AgoraRTC` variable is accessible in the components as `this.$AgoraRTC`.

Reference to inject in $root from [Nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/#inject-in-root--context)

Thanks to the support team of [Agora](https://agora.io)

Comment: If the package is not meant towards Vue but an usual JS package, this is indeed the way to go as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485267/8816585 `ssr: false` is still old and deprecated, you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason. And yes I removed the ssr part already. Cheers!