# How to use Scrollmagic.js with Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I seem to have successfully imported Scrollmagic.js, but I can't use it properly in vue file?

Down below is what I did:

1.install

```
npm i scrollmagic
```

2.*plugins* floder -> *ScrollMagic.client.js*

```js
import {defineNuxtPlugin} from '#app'
import * as ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp)=>{
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ScrollMagic)
})
```

3.I don't know how to use it in myvue file.But the browser show:

[image]

and the console always show:

*window is not defined*

Comment: You may use it like this: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic#usage You may also need to have an inject maybe, to have access to the instance with something like `$scrollMagic`. I didn't tried with Nuxt3 yet but this was the way for Nuxt2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485267/8816585

Comment: As for the last error, you can search for it with the exact wording + Nuxt, I've answered it already.