# How to use an installed npm package in vscode using .Vue framework?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, npm-install

I have installed a npm package, however i am using the vue framework. The npm package is written in JS, but Vue's syntax is different that JS, even though it is a JS framework. How can i use the package in my vue project?

I have mainly installed the npm package and unsure how to translate what is written in it. i am new to coding and only recently learnt JS and now trying Vue

Comment: Can you provide more details about the package you're trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

The Vue syntax is still some standard JS, just with some added sugar, and as such, NPM packages can be imported inside your Vue components `<script>` tag via a simple import.

For example:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      axios.get(...)
    }
  }
}
```

Some packages might expose more defined methods and properties for you to import, in which case you can use what is called "destructuring" in order to import just what you need from the package as opposed to the whole package:

```
import { method_1, method_3, property_a } from 'myPackage';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myComponentProperty: property_a
    }
  },
  ...
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      const a = 'something';
      const b = method_1(a);
      
      return b;
    }
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, just find your package on https://www.npmjs.com/ and look at the instructions to use it, you'll have some examples on how to import and use it in your project.

Comment: Not everything is as simple to use tho and some package are tightly coupled to DOM manipulation/alike. Overall, you _can_ loose quite some advantages of Vue's reactivity.

Comment: Of course, this is an overly generalised answer but it should bring to this user a few leads and essentially point toward the `import` declaration which is the most common way to import a package inside a Vue component.

Comment: For sure. And yeah, there are no other ways to `import` anything into a frontend app tbh (`require` is long gone).

Answer (score 0):

Depends of the package you're using, if it's a simple date formater or if it's a whole calendar with baked-in features already.
The first one can be chained/nested into a method as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253395/8816585).

---

The other one is quite harder and **more advanced**, and will require the usage of methods linked below:

- if you want to achieve that in Nuxt (meta-framework mainly used with Vue for SSR): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485267/8816585
- for Vue, I guess this is still the way to go: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject

[This article](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-api-call-organization-and-decoupling/) is a bit old but still relevant as of how to abstract and plug some vanilla JS code to your VueJS instance. I'm sure you can find even more like this one.

---

Since you're new to JS/Vue, I recommend that you take things easy overall and use only the first type of packages that could be easily integrated.
Overall, get used to the whole ecosystem + way of doing things.

An easy way is sometimes to prefix/suffix your package, for example [swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) can also be used thanks to `swiper/vue`.
You can find a nice list of cool packages here overall: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Comment: Just to make things clear to user20371345, the provide and inject Vue methods are NOT to "provide" or "inject" a package in Vue, I believe @kissu only used them as example to point to the way those methods are "imported" from the Vue package into a component.

Comment: @Ninowis it is the way to go if you actually want it to be plugged to your Vue instance and accessible from anywhere. Importing a package is okay but at some point, you will need to handle more complex use-cases without a whole redefinition + duplication of the thing, hence where you will need such pattern. I edit my answer to specify that this is an advanced pattern (on top of recommending to play around with Vue before this path). Your example is great but also quite over-simplified/naive and will not really scale in the long term.